# Error while opening RIDE (robot framework IDE) using ride.py command

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am new to robot framework and I am trying to setup robot framework on my system. I have `python 3.8.2`, `pip 20.0.2` and `Robot Framework 3.1.2` (Python 3.8.1 on win32). And in the environment variable I have set the paths:

> "C:\Users\pacharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"
>   and
>   "C:\Users\pacharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\robot"
>   and
>   "C:\Users\pacharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32"

I have also installed `wxpython` (when I type pip freeze it shows the wxPython==4.0.7.post2) 
So the problem is after successfully installing all these, when I ride to open the `RIDE` using `ride.py` command it showing the below message. [image]

[image]

These  are the errors that it's showing

Answer (score 1):

A simple search would lead to the project page, where you can see that RIDE 1.7.4.1 it is not compatible with Python 3.8.

> Attention, don’t install RIDE on Python 3.8 (wait for release of version 2.0)
>   Or you can install from development, where running on Python 3.8 is supported (since February 2020)

https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was the compatibility issue. Now, its working fine. Next time onwards, I will check the project page or other documentation clearly before posting any issues. Thanks.